# C++ How can you Point to a Private Inherited Class Object Within a Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, private-inheritance

I am learning about class inheritance and I wanted to know how one can create a pointer to a class that was inherited privately by another class? I've included a simple example below. Many thanks to those who help in answering this question.

```
class A: private std::string
{
public: 
A(){}
~A(){}

void func1() 
{
// I want a pointer that points to the std::string object. Then I will use that pointer in this function
}
};
```

Comment: Must read: [Don't inherit from std types](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/). You're getting ready to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pointer to a class"

Answer (score 2):

As simple as

```
std::string* p = this;
```

Since `A` derives from `std::string`, `A*` is implicitly convertible to `std::string*` (where that base class is in fact accessible, of course).

Comment: @PeteBecker `func1` is too a member function, so there is too `this` pointer.